# IfController not getting executed in the Jmeter that is defined under the forEach controller

Tags: jmeter

[image]IfController not getting executed in my Jmeter that is defined under forEach controller.

Trying to use Jmeter to perform the below scenario. Can this be achieved?

"- Connect to the database (Used a JDBC connection)
- Run a SQL to fetch a list of batch records say it returns B1, B2 and B3 batches (Used a JDBC request)
- For each of the batch records obtained, run a SQL to fetch corresponding shipments (Used a ForEach Controller and JDBC request)
      - if the count of shipments in each batch is less than 5 (Used a If Controller)
          - Run a new SQL to fetch new set of shipment for the same batch (Used a ForEach Controller)
         -For each shipment, call a application API (Used a HTTP request)"

I see the first ForEach Controller is excuted but I dont see the if Controller being executed. 
To make the condition simple in the if controller i used this condition - 1==1 and also tried with this (${__jexl3(vars.get("JMeterThread.last_sample_ok")=="true" && (vars.getObject("shipmentCount1").size() < 2 ),)})

Comment: your if is above foreach and not under

Comment: there is a foreach above as well and also under if. Will the if controller not work under foreach ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to **remove parentheses** from your If Controller's condition because it results into `(true)` which cannot be cast to `true` hence your If Controller's children are not executed

Correct expression: `${__jexl3(vars.get("JMeterThread.last_sample_ok")=="true" && (vars.getObject("shipmentCount1").size() < 2 ),)}`

Demo:

[image]

If Controller setup just in case:

[image]

Always check [JMeter Functions and/or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) values using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) combination